# AWS Beanstalk RDS ERROR While Running Migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I can connect to the database.However, when I try to run database migrations for creating a table in AWS RDS. I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xxx.xx", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

I'm using node js with PostgreSQL. I've made changes found online by making changes in the `pg_hba.conf` file. I've also added `listen_addresses = '*'`.

Could this be a AWS RDS issue with VPC/Security Groups or something i'm missing ?

I want migrations to run

Comment: It's not possible to edit `pg_hba.conf` or `listen_addresses` for RDS servers, so it is entirely unclear where you edited those. The error is not a security group issue, because you are successfully connecting to the database server. After the network connection is established you are getting an authentication error back from the DB server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : fixed it , the issue was in inbound connections that wasn’t allowing migrations to run.